# Number of permutation

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I can't guess how to compute number of permutations when I have $f$ fields and number $a$ of elements to distribute among them. Such that sum must be equal to $a$. Could you enlighten me and refer to some reading about it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  This is identical to partitioning $a$ into $f$ parts.  Think about how many ways $f-1$ "markers" can be distributed into $a+f-1$ positions.  The $f-1$ markers will divide the set $\{1,2,\dots, a\}$ into $f$ parts.  (This should be enough, but f you need more explanation let me know.  Also, let me know if I am interpreting your question correctly.  The term "permutations" seems a bit confusing in this context.)

Answer (score 0):

You either want the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $a$ into $f$ parts (if you don't care about the order, so $5=1+2+2$ is the same as $5=2+2+1$) or the number of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) if the order does matter.  It is a large subject.